# Codeigniter: Pass form variable into URI

Tags: codeigniter

Not sure if this can be done but it seems my main issue is because i have a default route to a method called "index." I want to be able to list all users tagged with a specific keyword. In addition, users can search for other users based on these keywords.

i.e.
www.domain.com/tags/apples
www.domain.com/tags/oranges
www.domain.com/tags/blueberry

It works fine if I go to the URL manually. I'm having issues getting it to work with a form field.

Snippet of the form_open:

```
<?=form_open('tags/');?>

<p>Search for Tag: <input type="text" name="tag" /></p>    
<p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
```

Here's a snippet of my controller:

```
function index() {
    $data['result'] = $this->tags_model->searchByTag($this->uri->segment(2));
    $this->load->view('tags_view', $data);
}
```

Here's a snippet of my router:

```
$route['tags'] = "tags/index";
$route['tags/(:any)'] = "tags/index/$1";
```

Now, I can easily fix all this if I have a method called search, but I don't want the URL to show up as www.domain.com/tags/search/orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redirecting the URL and passed the keyword into the URI.

i.e. domain.com/tags/view/

Answer (score 5):

When you create your form you set it to use `POST` variables instead of `GET`, that way they don't go through the url, that's codeigniter's default method for forms.

So your form_open code will generate the following code:

```
 <form method="post" action="tags/" />
```

If you want them to got through url though, call the form opener this way instead:

```
form_open('tags/', array('method' => 'get'));
```

The same applies to any other attributes you want to specify for the form, just follow the same pattern `attribute_name => attribute_value` inside the array.

More info on the [user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Comment: Ok, that seems to do the following ...

tags?tag=orange ... how do I get that to "rewrite?"

Comment: I get a 404 Page cannot be found. ughhhh

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your form will be submitting all it's data to "/tags", with nothing trailing it, as POST data doesn't come in as part of the URL.  Even if it was a GET request however, I don't think that CodeIgniter will take anything out of the querystring and use it as part of the routing segments.

I think what you should do is have a small Javascript function that automatically updates the form `action` parameter to be `tags/<select option value>` whenever the select value is changed.  This way it will submit to the right place.  In order to handle non-javascript enabled browsers, you could have a default action called tags/search that would simply analyze your form data and put out a 301 redirect to the proper `tags/<location>` once you'd figured it out.

It seems like a bit of overkill here however, as you could really point the form at `tags/index` and not worry about it.  I'm not sure search engines index form submission locations, and even if they did, they certainly wouldn't index a form that submits to dynamic URIs in the way that you want it to.  You could still link to the search result pages using `tags/apples`, etc, but the form could work quite normally just by going to `tags/index`.